# React: Mutating instance of Ref object in child components

Tags: reactjs

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.data = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.data.current = []
  }

  render() {
    return <Child data={data} />
  }
}

const Child = ({ data }) => {

  const onDelete = (idx) => {
    data.splice(idx, 1)
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={(index) => onDelete(index)}>Delete</button>
  )
}
```

I need this ref to be an array for some complicated to explain reason, although the code is doing the job I am not sure if it is right to mutate the `ref` prop in the child component. My question is: If the prop I am passing to the child component is not a state in the parent, then is it okay to mutate it? Or in refs case does that work differently? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can't have a `ref` and `key` prop (see docs) so I believe this code actually does not work. Usually, that's no the use case for refs, what you gain in mutating the ref? It won't trigger a render, so it's just stale data sitting there.

Comment: React refs aren't props. They are special, like react keys. You've attached the ref to `Child` so it's current value ***is*** the `Child`. Check [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html). You can have `Child` forward the ref. Refs are designed to be mutable, but whether or not it's ok to mutate the current value at any specific time is entirely up to your use-case. Can you provide a more practical [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example?

Comment: My mistake, It was actually array of data I was referring to, i edited the code

Comment: Just dont mutate anth)

Comment: Generally, refs are used for 2 purposes, accessing underlying DOM nodes and storing values you want to persist *through* render cycles. Based upon the nature of your snippet deleting an element of an array passed as a prop it doesn't seem useful, and as @DennisVash correctly points out, won't trigger any rerenders, so the prop value can become out-of-sync with anything rendered. I guess if you say it is working then I say make sure you have it clearly documented in the code so any dev later (including yourself) won't see it and wonder what is happening and why.

Comment: @DrewReese 'storing values you want to persist through render cycles' would suit my case, I guess. This array is being passed to many components as a prop and only in one component it is mutated. Obviously it should not cause re-render but the value is being updated in every component thats using the array as a prop